# Error on instalation and startup on RabbitMQ-Server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, rabbitmq, chef-infra, dpkg

I'm trying install [Tomcat7 chef cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat) , and tomcat have a dependency on RabbitMQ-Server.
The problem is: When i make te instalattion of RabbitMQ, returns a error:

```
    * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server 
    * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                             [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: erro ao processar rabbitmq-server (--configure):
```

What i want: if somebody have a idea of install tomcat7 to deploy a WAR file, please, answer here or tell what is this error and how to correct.

Thanks

Comment: The cookbook has no dependency on RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks. after a long time, i discovered this. haha